# Xamarin Forms Media Plugin, Get stream or StorageFile from MediaFile

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, cross-platform, xamarin.winphone

For a PCL application I'm developing I'm using the media plugin for Xamarin Forms by jamesmontemagno ([Github Repo](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin)). I am mainly using the plugin for capturing photos through the device's camera, for this I'm using the TakeVideoAsync method (`Task<MediaFile> TakeVideoAsync(StoreVideoOptions options);`). It returns a `[MediaFile][2]` object.

The issue I'm facing is that I need to send the image as an email attachment. For this I will implement an "EmailSender" class which will have different implementations for every target platforms (I'm using the PCL approach). Right now I'm working on a Windows Phone 8.1 (Silverlight) implementation. I would like to use `Windows.ApplicationModel.Email.EmailManager` to send a `Windows.ApplicationModel.Email.EmailMessage`. An example implementation can be seen in [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28668762/1308385) (Look at the "ComposeEmail" method).

---

**What I need help with:** 
I want to find a way of retrieving the image file (perhaps either as an StorageFile or RandomAccessStream) in order to make an [EmailAttachment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.email.emailattachment.aspx) object from it. From the `MediaFile` returned by the `TakeVideoAsync` method in the media plugin I can get a `System.IO.Stream`, but I haven't found any way of converting it to a `RandomAccessStream` with the functionality of the .NET version my Xamarin Windows Phone 8.1

All suggestions will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A Stream object in Windows Phone 8.1 has a .AsRandomStream() extension method in the System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime library. IRandomStream has a .ToStream() extension method in same lib. You can also create a new RandomStream with
    IRandomAccessStream randomAccessStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
Hope that helps.